# trigger event and DOM manipulation like jQuery in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**jQuery**

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

$('.box').bind('mousedown', function(){
    alert('box class clicked');
});
```

**angular**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-click="boxClick()" class="box"></div>
        <div ng-click="boxClick()"  class="box"></div>
        <div ng-click="boxClick()"  class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.boxClick = function(){
        alert('box class clicked');
    }
});
```

Now I am learning **AngularJS**, if we see this, short and crispy will be jQuery, for a single click event we are writing these much of line code in  **AngularJS**, can anyone help me to write short as much as **jQuery**, how to select **DOM** element in **AngularJS** like **jQuery**, I am using `ng-click` to trigger **click event** in **AngularJS**, without that can I able to trigger **click event** in script tag itself. Thanks for replies in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1

Comment: If you're asking whether you can catch a `click` event without using `ng-click`, the answer is yes, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Internally angular uses light version of `jQuery` called `jqLite`. So, DOM selection in angular can be done using `jqLite` - [More Info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: @Huey because i don't want to write in html page

Comment: @Selva, I strongly suggest you check out Deblaton's link. Directives are a core feature and without them I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to use Angular.

Comment: thanks to all replies, I asked this question because need to follow some standard way..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using [`directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). this is a **standard** way in `angularjs` for this kind of situation.

The sample look like

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.directive('myDomDirective', function () {
        return {
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function () {
                   alert('You clicked me!');
                });
                element.bind('mouseenter', function () {
                    alert('You mouse entered me!');
                });
                element.bind('mouseleave', function () {
                     alert('You mouse leaved me!');
                });
            }
        };
    });
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     // do what you want like service calls and binding
   });
```

then call the directives in your any tag

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div my-dom-directive class="box"></div>
        <div my-dom-directive  class="box"></div>
        <div my-dom-directive  class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please take a look at this [document](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals) for more details

Comment: if i use above code getting error Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=myCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)

Comment: You need to add this line `app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {` my code have missed assigning controller

Comment: can u please update the answer, i checked but now no error, but no event triggered

Comment: can u please update answer with working code, bcoz will help all and also me

Comment: Yeah, please tell me !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75931/discussion-between-selva-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things i want you to notice that when you are working on DOM objects then it is better to do all the stuff in angular directives. As suggested in the answer.

i have created a demo and used this way:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
   <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-btn class="box">Btn1</div>
      <div ng-btn  class="box">Btn2</div>
      <div ng-btn  class="box">Btn3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and `controller` in app.js:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.boxClick = function(){ alert('clicked'); };
});
```

and `directive` in the app.js:

```
app.directive('ngBtn', function(){
  return {
     link:function(scope, element, attrs){
          angular.element(element).on('click', scope.boxClick);
     }
  };
});
```

#### [Check this sample demo at plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ml9T9C61xeL0QMGYAy95?p=preview)

---

In this answer you can see we have a controller `myCtrl` in the js and function `boxClick` is in the `$scope` of current controller, which alerts a message.

Now if you see the markup you can see a directive named `ng-btn` which we have used in the `directive` with the camelCase naming convention in angular with `ngBtn` in the module.

Now in the directive you can see it returns an object which links to a callback function with three params `(scope, element, attrs)`, where `scope` is  the current controller's scope, `element` is the one which has the `ng-btn` attribute. Now using `jqLite` in the `angular.element()` you can bind the event on the element and you can see the message poping out.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76062/discussion-on-answer-by-jai-trigger-event-and-dom-manipulation-like-jquery-in-an).